# SseEmitter closes automatically after a connection is established

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, server-sent-events

SseEmitter closes (completes) automatically after a connection is established.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/stream", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces=MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public SseEmitter getSseEmitter(@RequestBody @Valid SseSubscription subscription) {
    return service.sse(subscription);
}
```

Here is the sse method

```
    public SseEmitter sse(SseSubscription subscription) {

        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        emitter.onTimeout(emitter::complete);
        emitter.onError(e -> {
            repository.removeEmitter(subscription.getSubscribersId());
        });
        try {
            emitter.send(SseEmitter.event().name("SSE").data("Welcome!"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.info("Could not send sse notification.");
        }

        emitter.onCompletion(() -> repository.removeEmitter(subscription.getSubscribersId()));
        repository.addOrUpdate(subscription.getSubscribersId(), emitter);
        return emitter;
    }
```

What could be the reason for this?